# Is it possible to send a report in TestRail using commandline?

Tags: api, command-line, report, testrail

What I want to do is that I want to send a test-rail report specifically API Template on a specific email using a command line just by giving parameters like **email address** and **file type (PDF or HTML)**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide your code along with any errors/issues you are encountering.

Comment: So far all I did was doing research if this is possible since any of my researched results are not giving me any idea on how this needs to be done.